# Cambiar URL en .htacces para varios idiomas

Tags: php, url

estoy intentando cambiar todas las rutas de una página para que según el idioma que elija el usuario mediante sus respectivos enlaces (no por el idioma del navegador) se me vaya a la misma URL pero empezando por las iniciales de ese idioma.

Por ejemplo ahora mismo tengo una url así:

```
www.misitio.com/catalogo/producto
```

y quiero que ahora pueda funcionar así:

```
www.misitio.com/es/catalogo/producto

www.misitio.com/en/catalogo/producto

www.misitio.com/fr/catalogo/producto
```

hasta aquí lo veréis fácil, pero lo que necesito es que las 300 reglas de url que ya tengo en el htacces no haya que cambiarlas una a una metiendo cada idioma,

Supongo que tiene que haber alguna expresión regular para el htacces que se añada al principio para decir que todas las rutas que empiecen por ejemplo por **en/**  sigan funcionando con el resto de reglas que ya hay

No se he explicado bien el problema, espero que alguien lo entienda

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes  utilizar esta regla

```html
 RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/(.*)/([^/]+)/?$ /$2/$3.php?id=$1  [L,NC]
```

Donde:

- `([a-z]{2})` es el equivalente al idioma  (solo dos letras )
- `/(.*)/` Cualquier string  entre dos //
- `([^/]+)/?$` Cualquier palabra que puede o no terminar con /
- `[L]` Última regla: indica al servidor que deje de reescribir después de que se procese la directiva anterior
- `[NC]`
  Sin mayúsculas y minúsculas: define cualquier argumento asociado como insensible a mayúsculas y minúsculas.

**url de entrada**

```
https://www.misitio.com/es/catalogo/producto
```

**url de salida**

```
https://www.misitio.com/catalogo/producto.php?id=es
```

Puedes probar esta regla [AQUI](https://htaccess.madewithlove.com/)

Comment: Muchas gracias Wilfredo, pero no es eso lo que necesito. Necesito una regla como la que hay para redirigir del http al https o al dominio con o sin www. Es una regla que me sirva para que todas las url amigables que tengo en mi htaccess se le añada las iniciales del idioma. Lo que me has enviado tendría que hacerlo para cada RewriteRule que ya tengo con cada url de mi sitio y eso no me viene bien porque son muchísimas. Gracias de todas formas.